# How to send iOS push notifications with PHP?

Tags: php, ios, swift, notifications, apple-push-notifications

I am trying to send push notifications with PHP to an iOS device. I have the device token, but I don't know how to set up the server itself. I have been able to register the device with `UserNotifications` in the `AppDelegate.swift` file. I am using Xcode 10 and Swift 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two options actually

1. Send the payload to **APNS** by yourself.
2. Rely on 3rd party to Interact with **APNS**.

**1. Send to APNS directly:**
There is comprehensive guide to send Push payload to APNS [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/sending_notification_requests_to_apns).

**2. Rely on a 3rd party:**
Many 3rd party services provide a free solution. Among them, Firebase is pretty popular, backed up by Google, and push to iOS/Android/Web platform all in one. [This guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client) will walk you through how to configure your iOS client to integrate Firebase/Messaging SDK. To send push payload to Firebase, use [this guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref), which will allow you through simple **HTTP** call with necessary payload to send the push.

NB: Among these two options, I would suggest to use Firebase to send your push. Your PHP end's complexity will reduce to just maintain firebase instance token, and the payload creation is much more simplified by using the firebase for different platforms.